# Spring Boot entity not persisted (yet)

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying to trigger an event whenever a new entity is created in the database. To do so I am using an event and listener. I pass the Listing entity directly and try to do stuff with it, however when I try to get relational objects is always returns zero.

ListingService.java

```java
package com.example.demo.service;

import com.example.demo.domain.Listing;
import com.example.demo.domain.ListingProduct;
import com.example.demo.domain.Platform;
import com.example.demo.domain.Product;
import com.example.demo.dto.ListingDto;
import com.example.demo.dto.ProductDto;
import com.example.demo.event.ListingCreatedEvent;
import com.example.demo.repository.ListingProductRepository;
import com.example.demo.repository.ListingRepository;
import com.example.demo.repository.PlatformRepository;
import com.example.demo.repository.ProductRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationEventPublisher;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class ListingService {

    @Autowired
    private ListingRepository listingRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;

    @Autowired
    private PlatformRepository platformRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ListingProductRepository listingProductRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher;

    public Listing createListingWithProducts(ListingDto listingDto) {
        Optional<Listing> listingOptional = this.listingRepository.findByUniqueIdentifier(listingDto.getListing());

        if (listingOptional.isPresent())
            throw new ResponseStatusException(
                    HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "Listing with this unique identifier already exists."
            );

        Platform platform = this.platformRepository.findByName(listingDto.getPlatform())
                .orElseGet(() -> this.platformRepository.save(new Platform(listingDto.getPlatform())));

        Listing listing = new Listing(listingDto.getListing());
        listing.setPlatform(platform);

        this.listingRepository.save(listing);

        List<ListingProduct> listingProducts = new ArrayList<>();

        for (ProductDto productDto : listingDto.getProducts()) {
            Product product = this.productRepository.findByName(productDto.getName())
                    .orElseGet(() -> this.productRepository.save(new Product(productDto.getName())));

            ListingProduct listingProduct = new ListingProduct();
            listingProduct.setProduct(product);
            listingProduct.setListing(listing);
            listingProduct.setListingType(productDto.getListingType());
            listingProduct.setCredits(productDto.getCredits());

            listingProducts.add(listingProduct);
        }
        this.listingProductRepository.saveAll(listingProducts);
        this.applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(new ListingCreatedEvent(listing));
        return listing;
    }
}
```

ListingCreatedEvent.java

```
package com.example.demo.event;

import com.example.demo.domain.Listing;

public class ListingCreatedEvent {
    private Listing listing;

    public ListingCreatedEvent(Listing listing) {
        this.listing = listing;
    }

    public Listing getListing() {
        return this.listing;
    }
}
```

ListingEventListener.java

```
package com.example.demo.listener;

import com.example.demo.domain.Listing;
import com.example.demo.event.ListingCreatedEvent;
import com.example.demo.repository.AlertRepository;
import com.example.demo.repository.ListingRepository;
import com.example.demo.service.RateLimitedTelegramService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.event.EventListener;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.Optional;

@Component
public class ListingEventListener {
    @Autowired
    private RateLimitedTelegramService rateLimitedTelegramService;

    @Autowired
    private AlertRepository alertRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ListingRepository listingRepository;

    @EventListener
    public void handleListingCreatedEvent(ListingCreatedEvent event) {

        Optional<Listing> optionalListing = this.listingRepository.findById(event.getListing().getId());

        if (optionalListing.isEmpty())
            return;

        Listing listing = optionalListing.get();

        System.out.println(listing.getListingProducts().size());
    }
}
```

What have I tried so far? To be honest Spring Boot is quite new for me but I assume it has something to do with having the database not yet updated. So I added `@Transactional` to my Service but that didn't work.

Then I tried to flush the database manually in my service, but that also didn't work.

The weird thing is, in my `handleListingCreatedEvent` method, if I get a random Listing by an ID it works, and it does print the size. However the newly passed Listing can't be found by the ID in the database (it does return an ID if I do listing.getId()) and I can't access the `event.getListing().getListingProducts().size()` directly.

Comment: I would guess that the transaction hasn't been committed at that point. You could use `@TransactionalEventListener` so that you listener is call when the commit of the transaction in which the message was sent is complete.

Comment: @tgdavies I just tried your suggestion but the same problem still exists. I added `@Transactional` to my Service method aswel, because I read that `@TransactionEventListener` must be fired from within a transaction.